# Parsing JSON array of objects

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, json, .net-1.1

I need to store a set of values which I get from my C# code to a javascript array.
Im getting an error .. Can someone tell what the error is ? 
Im using this jcode.

```
 $.get('Dataextract.aspx', function (data, textStatus) {
        alert('Status is ' + textStatus);//success
        alert('JSON data string is: ' + data);//string as below

    var JSONdata = data;
    eval(JSONdata);//error here-> expected ;
    alert(JSONdata.rowval[0].CustomerID);

}, 'text');
```

I am using an ajax query to retrieve an array of JSON object. the data objects value that i get is something like this as string.

```
{"rowval" :[{"CustomerID":12"Title":"Mr.""FirstName":"Johnny""MiddleName":"A.""LastName":"Caprio""CompanyName":"Bikes and Motorbikes""RowNumber":10},{"CustomerID":16"Title":"Mr.""FirstName":"Christopher""MiddleName":"R.""LastName":"Beck""CompanyName":"Bulk Discount Store""RowNumber":11},{"CustomerID":18"Title":"Mr.""FirstName":"David""MiddleName":"J.""LastName":"Liu""CompanyName":"Catalog Store""RowNumber":12},{"CustomerID":19"Title":"Mr.""FirstName":"John""MiddleName":"A.""LastName":"Beaver""CompanyName":"Center Cycle Shop""RowNumber":13},{"CustomerID":20"Title":"Ms.""FirstName":"Jean""MiddleName":"P.""LastName":"Handley""CompanyName":"Central Discount Store""RowNumber":14},{"CustomerID":21"Title":"FirstName":"Jinghao""MiddleName":"LastName":"Liu""CompanyName":"Chic Department Stores""RowNumber":15},{"CustomerID":22"Title":"Ms.""FirstName":"Linda""MiddleName":"E.""LastName":"Burnett""CompanyName":"Travel Systems""RowNumber":16},{"CustomerID":23"Title":"Mr.""FirstName":"Kerim""MiddleName":"LastName":"Hanif""CompanyName":"Bike World""RowNumber":17},{"CustomerID":24"Title":"Mr.""FirstName":"Kevin""MiddleName":"LastName":"Liu""CompanyName":"Eastside Department Store""RowNumber":18},{"CustomerID":25"Title":"Mr.""FirstName":"Donald""MiddleName":"L.""LastName":"Blanton""CompanyName":"Coalition Bike Company""RowNumber":19},{"CustomerID":28"Title":"Ms.""FirstName":"Jackie""MiddleName":"E.""LastName":"Blackwell""CompanyName":"Commuter Bicycle Store""RowNumber":20}]}
```

Here is my C# code that is generating the JSON

```
sb.Append("{\"rowval\" :");
            sb.Append("[");
            if (table != null)
            {
                foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
                {
                    sb.Append("{");
                    if (row.Table != null && row.Table.Columns != null && row.Table.Columns.Count > 0)
                    {
                        foreach (DataColumn column in row.Table.Columns)
                        {
                            parseMember(row[column], column.ColumnName, sb);
                        }
                    }
                    sb.Append("},");
                }
            }
            sb.Append("]");
            sb.Append("}");

            sqlcon.Close();
            Response.Write(sb);



        }

        private static void parseMember(object val, string memberName, StringBuilder sb)
        {
            Type t = val.GetType();

            if (memberName != null && memberName.Trim().Length > 0)
                sb.AppendFormat("\"{0}\":", memberName);
            if (typeof(string) == t || typeof(char) == t)
                sb.AppendFormat("\"{0}\"", val.ToString());
            else
                sb.AppendFormat("{0}", val.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: Can you edit and post the C# code you're using to create the (faulty) JSON object? Look at the quotation marks, with spaces, and you'll see that they're mismatched: `"CustomerID":"25" Title":" "Mr." "FirstName":" "Donald""`...

Comment: yeah sorry . posted the wrong json.. have corrected

Comment: ^ was manually editing the wrong json that why there were errors left.. have copy pasted the json now. do see

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are getting `json` then specifying `dataType` equal to `json as 4th argument in`$.get`will parse the json which you can iterate using the`each` method of jquery, like

```
 $.get('Dataextract.aspx', function (data, textStatus) {
        alert('Status is ' + textStatus);//success
        alert('JSON data string is: ' + data);//string as below
    // no need for eval
   // var JSONdata = data;
   // eval(JSONdata);//error here-> expected ;
    alert(JSONdata.rowval[0].CustomerID);

}, "json"); // <--
```

or you can parse the json explicitly like

```
 $.get('Dataextract.aspx', function (data, textStatus) {
        alert('Status is ' + textStatus);//success
        alert('JSON data string is: ' + data);//string as below

    var JSONdata = $.parseJSON(data);
   // eval(JSONdata);//error here-> expected ;  again no need for the eval
    alert(JSONdata.rowval[0].CustomerID);

}, 'text');
```

---

**update**

the json you are forming is not correct, for validating your json you can visit [www.jsonlint.com](http://www.jsonlint.com), this is the valid json

```
{
    "rowval": [
        {
            "CustomerID": 12,  // <-- you are missing the commas 
            "Title": "Mr.",
            "FirstName": "Johnny",
            "MiddleName": "A.",
            "LastName": "Caprio",
            "CompanyName": "Bikes and Motorbikes",
            "RowNumber": 10
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: +1. Of course this still will only work if the JSON is properly formed.

Comment: now the error is expected - }  :P json has been updated above

Comment: @KshitijBanerjee the json formed is not valid, see the answer update

Comment: Thanks! i was definitely missing that in my convertor! will update about this soon

Answer (score 0):

You need two classes -call them RoVal and Customer, for example- and define them as so:

```
class RowVal
{

    public List<Customer> Customers {get;set;}
}

class Customer
{
   public int ID {get;set;}
   public string Title{get;set;}
   public string FirstName {get;set;}
   //and so on

}
```

Now you can deserialize that JSON string as so

```
JavascriptSerializer serializer = new JavascriptSerializer();
RowVal rowVal =    serializer.Deserialize<RowVal>(yourJSonstring);
```

Comment: I have to develop my application in asp 1.1 which does not have javascriptserializer

Comment: The use JSON.NET if it's possible (I don't know if JSON.NET is supported on 1.1). You should have tagged your question accordingly.